# Image with a min-height and height of 100% for large browsers

Tags: background, height, background-image, css

I want a background-image that only resizes if the browser is larger than the image size. Therefore, I need a min-height equal to the image pixel height, but also a height of 100% if the browser's height is larger than the image height.

I know I might be able to do this with a div, but would rather use the background-image & background-size CSS properties. This is all I have so far:

```
    body{
       background-image:url('Images/newBG.jpg');background-size: 1911px 824px;
    }
```

Any idea where I should put the min-height or if this is even possible without using a div? If someone has the div solution, I would appreciate that also.